# How to disable cache for ag-grid when paging to previous pages

Tags: ag-grid

I'm using ag-grid with server-side row model and pagination, just the previous and next buttons, no scrolling. I want ag-grid to load data (so calling `getRows()`) on every click to next **and** previous.
It works fine for next page but the data for previous page is never loaded again from server.

I'm using this config properties for pagination and cache:

```
rowModelType: 'serverSide',
pagination: true,
paginationPageSize: 10,
cacheBlockSize: 10,
maxBlocksInCache: 0
```

More or less completely disabling cache on client side. Any hint how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is your solution:

```
 maxBlocksInCache = 1;
```

`cacheBlockSize` - should be the same as `paginationPageSize` (cuz it would one visible 'scope' - for block storage, so remember to bind it to one property) and then - block storage is a `maxBlocksInCache` - should be the **one** only (cuz one visible block is equal to one block in cache)

```
rowModelType: 'serverSide',
pagination: true,
paginationPageSize: 10,
cacheBlockSize: 10,
maxBlocksInCache: 1
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://plnkr.co/edit/jKC9gykyi7nvL6DE)